# EmberJs does not update record after it was saved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I create a record via `const myRecord = this.store.createRecord('myType', myObject)` and then `myRecord.save()` the request is send via adapter to server. Data are successfully saved and server returns all data back to client. It goes back through serializer, via the `normalize()` hook.

Problem is that Ember does not update the `myRecord` object with properties returned from server, for example `id` or `version` ...

When I refresh the page, all properties are there (of course).

I have similar issue with updating records. Each record in my application has a version property which is checked by server. The version is incremenented on each save. This is to for data safety. Problem is that when I try to update the record several times, then only the first attempt succeeds. The reason is that the `version` is not updated after the request gets back from server. (And yes, server returns the updated version)

This is a surprising behaviour for me and it seems to me like an intended functionality as suggested here - https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/issues/265. (but that post is from 2013 and suggested solution does not work for me).

Any ideas?

For completenes, here is the relevant code (simplified and renamed)

**myModel**

```
export default Ember.Model.extend({
    typedId: attr('string') // this serves as an ID
    version: attr('string'), 
    name: attr('string'),
    markup: attr('number'), 
});
```

**myAdapter**

```
RESTAdapter.extend({
    createRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
        // call to serializer
        const serializedData = this.serialize(snapshot, options);

        const url = 'http://some_internal_api_url';
        // this returns a promise
        const result =  this.ajax(url, 'POST', serializedData);

        return result;
    },
});
```

**mySerializer**

```
JSONSerializer.extend({
    idAttribute: 'typedId',

    serialize(snapshot, options) {     
        var json = this._super(...arguments);
        // perform some custom operations
        // on the json
        return json;
    },

    normalize(typeClass, hash) {
        hash.data.id = hash.data.typedId;

        hash.data.markup = hash.data.attribute1;
        hash.data.version = parseInt(hash.data.version, 10);

        return hash;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root cause was in the serializer's `normalize()` method.
There should be call to `this._super.apply(this, arguments);` which then writes in the changes in Data Store. Otherwise they are not reflected there. See the documentation http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html#method_normalize

So the working code looks something like this

```
normalize(typeClass, hash) {
        hash.data.id = hash.data.typedId;

        hash.data.markup = hash.data.attribute1;
        hash.data.version = parseInt(hash.data.version, 10);

        return this._super.apply(this, [typeClass, hash.data]);
   }
```

Most likely you call this version

```
return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
```